# Append elements to element based on attrs on click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to append or insertAfter all child row `<tr>` elements to a parent row `<tr>` element on click based on certain attrs having the same id.

I have a table "#example". and a few `<tr>` that are out of order. 
I have try append(), apppendTo(), insertAfter(), but to no avail.

Please see my code:

```
//HTML
<table id="example">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="parent" data-id="23">...</tr>
        <tr class="parent" data-id="20">...</tr>
        <tr class="child" data-parent="23">...</tr>
        <tr class="child" data-parent="23">...</tr>
        <tr class="child" data-parent="20">...</tr>
    </tbody>
</table>



//jQuery
$("#example tbody").on("click", "tr.parent" function () {
    var parentID = $(this).parents("tr").attr("data-id");
    var childRow = $("tr[data-parent="+parentID+"]");
    var parentRow = $(this).parents("tr[data-id="+parentID+"]");

    childRow.append(parentRow);
});
```

What I am trying to accomplish is this on click:

```
<table id="example">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="parent" data-id="23">...</tr>
        <tr class="child" data-parent="23">...</tr>
        <tr class="child" data-parent="23">...</tr>
        <tr class="parent" data-id="20">...</tr>
        <tr class="child" data-parent="20">...</tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't see any `data-id` attributes (nor any `a.movebtn`s)

Comment: Sorry, I fixed my typos, again

Comment: Also, `append()` adds and element as a child.  From your secondary snippet it looks like you want to keep them as siblings.  Which would be using a form of `after()`, `before()`, `insertAfter()`, or `insertBefore()` depending on the order of elements you do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AH! HAd the element vars mixed up.
and use after() per @Taplar

```
parentRow.after(childRow);
```